# mysql 5.5 upgrade - large performance loss

Tags: mysql, performance, upgrade

I upgraded one of our boxes to MySQL 5.5 over the weekend. It hosts several hundred tables scattered over a few Tb.

We run jobs that throw data onto this box every night (~50-100 Gb). Typically this process takes 1-2 hours. Since the upgrade the process is now taking 8-9 hours.

We're using (essentially) the same my.cnf from 5.1.52 but something is clearly amiss. Suggestions on where to look?

Running RHEL5 16GbRAM 8 cores (2.8Ghz xeon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once saw something similar after an upgrade. What you'll probably need to do is put in some simple profiling to find out which query(s) are taking the longest. Then do an `explain` on those queries to see what is taking so long. If its not readily apparent, if you can downgrade and do an `explain` on the query running on the old database you can compare the 2.

In my case I dont remember the exact fix, but it was something **extremely** trivial that changed a query from taking about .01 seconds to about 7 seconds.

Comment: None of the queries have been changed since the 'upgrade'. In fact, nothing except the version of the MySQL instance.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of this. My tip still stands. MySQL can change the way it processes a query from one version to the next.

Comment: k. Ill go the logging / explain route and see where things have gone amiss.

Comment: turned out to be a stored function that behaved *very* differently after the upgrade. used 'show processlist' to see who is unhappy.